# Use same ip from two diffent computers using vpn or other

Tags: networking, router, vpn

My problem is simple to explain but I do not know how to solve it

I have two computers, each one in a different location. Each house have a dsl internet access with its own router. I'd like to connect both computers using the same router and ip.

So: 
House A - Computer 1 - router netgear
House B - Computer 2 - router tplink

I want that computer 1 and computer 2 could browse internet using the same router and ip.

Maybe a vpn? Installing a raspberry with squid? Any hint welcome!

The problem is how to connect a computer sitting on LAN A to a remote lan B through internet and go out on internet using the IP used by LAN B adsl router?

Comment: You need to tell us what problem we're solving, not just how you plan to solve it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  you write "You need to tell us what problem we're solving, not just how you plan to solve it." <--  no he doesnt

Comment: @barlop He does if he wants to get answers that will solve his problem. Otherwise, we're just guessing. (Fortunately, he sort of did.)

Answer (score 1):

That is what a VPN would do.  You need to set up a VPN server at the remote location. And VPN client on the other.

Windows supports doing that.

A set up I have done is each comp would have its own private IP but viewed externally they'd have the IP of the NAPT router at the remote location.  The NAPT router port fowards to a VPN server when a VPN client connects.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is how to connect a computer sitting on LAN A to a remote lan B through internet and go out on internet using the IP used by LAN B adsl router?

This is one of the problems solved by a VPN, the other being secrecy (the connection between A and B is alway encrypted; it is not encrypted when it leaves B).

There are many different types of VPN, you may just skim [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) for this. The important thing is that you clarify what you want to do. You may have:

1. A VPN connecting one pc on A and one PC on B only;
2. The same, but the pc in A can be used as a router by all pcs in A, so that all of them, not always but when they wish, go thru B and seem to come from B;
3. A VPN connecting the **router** of A and a pc of B. This way, **all** pcs of A, at all times, are routed thru B. This can be weakened: pcs 1, 2 and 3 are routed thru B, while pcs and are not. What makes this scenario 
   attractive is that it has a centralized structure, so that you  need to install the VPN only once (but your router must support acting as VPN server, not all routers do).
4. A VPN connecting the two routers, making it look like network A and B belong to the same LAN, and anything can be shared between the two nets. You may then decide whether you want the traffic to be routed thru A, or thru B, or separately thru A and thru B.

Also, it is important to know which routers and which OSes on your pcs you are using. It is **always** possible to connect two pcs thru a VPN, while the routers need special capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to have a router in front of the modem, and connect computers to the router.  You would then only need one DSL or cable modem.

You connect the modem to the router.  You then connect all of the computers to the router, which now serves as an IP address server for computers connecting to it.

Hard-wired computers (ie the ones with a cable running to it) do not need an authority, since the actual physical cable is the authority.  Wireless ones do need an authority, which is the name you give your router.

So the modem connecting outside shares the connection with the router, and any computing using the router.  But from the internet, it appears as a single device.

Inside the network, you can plug dozens of devices into the network, and share data and connections with them.  Such connections are on a 'local network', not a VPN.

Inside your network, you configure the operating system to find a DNS server (which you point to your router, usually 192.168.0.1, but you can reconfigure the router to use any 192.168.xx.xx number.)

Once you have access to the DNS server, the broswer will automatically find the internet, although you might still need to answer questions as before (phone number etc).

VPN is a kind of local network, where the internet is part of a cable.  In essence, it allows you to log into your home network from a different city, by passing local internet calls over the internet.  This is not what is called for here.

1. If you want to use the internet as part of the cable, the different modems will have different IP addresses, and these addresses are decided by the IP, not by you.  You might have to talk to your ISP about this.

   2. If you mean to simply transfer data, a cross-over cable or a local network is the way to go.  Each computer could still have its own router and be on the internet.  In this case, you give each router a different IP address, like 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2, and configure each router to give numbers out in different ranges.  Then the OS is configured to look for router 192.168.0.1 or 2, and you should get a local network with two different external lines.
   3. If the intent is to eliminate a DSL connection, then you can hook the modem up to the router, and let the router share the internet.
   4. You really only need VPN if you plan a much further line, such as inter-city.